# sqlite match operator

Tags: android, sqlite

On Android i would like to use a query similar to this:

```
SELECT docid FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH '("sqlite database" OR "sqlite library") AND linux'
```

http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3

The problem is that I got a "malformed match expression error". When I do more basic match query it works, and it seems the issue might be because of the parentheses.

When I use exactly the same statement (except the table the column name) the error is the same.

The complete error message:

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = statement aborts at 7: 
[SELECT * FROM namedays WHERE names MATCH '("sqlite database" OR "sqlite library") AND linux';] 
malformed MATCH expression: [("sqlite database" OR "sqlite library") AND linux], db=/data/data/org.xyz/databases/data
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please post the exact code (including the query) that is failing, and the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information in it.

Comment: How are you creating your fts3 table? And further more, how are you constructing the query that turns out malformed?

Comment: The table is created by: create virtual table namedays using fts3(_id, names, marked).

The query is a simple string passed to SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you do not have SQLite compiled with the SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS option. As such, you can only use the [Standard Query Syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_2), not the [Enhanced Query Syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_1)

You can easily verify this by executing the [`compile_options` pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options). For example, we see that my sqlite3 doesn't have the enhanced syntax:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA compile_options;
DISABLE_DIRSYNC
ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_RTREE
ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY
SECURE_DELETE
TEMP_STORE=1
THREADSAFE=1
```

Comment: So this means the only way to do this is by intersecting multiple SELECTs ?

Comment: Yes indeed as there is then no support for parenthesis.

Comment: How can we enable pragma using sqliteHelper ?