# How to query an external content FTS4 table but return additional columns from the original content table

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I am creating an [FTS4 external content table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2_2) in SQLite like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col_a, col_b, col_text);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table USING fts4(content="t2", col_text);
```

I'm using an external content table so that I don't need to store duplicate values of `col_text` in `fts_table`. I'm only indexing `col_text` because `col_a` and `col_b` don't need to be indexed.

However, when I do a query of `fts_table` like this

```
SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE fts_table MATCH 'something';
```

I don't have access to `col_a` and `col_b` from the content table `t2`. How do return all these columns (`col_a`, `col_b`, `col_text`) from a single FTS query?

**Update**

I tried using the `notindexed=column_name` option as in

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table USING fts4(content="t2", col_a, col_b, col_text, notindexed=col_a, notindexed=col_b);
```

This should work for some people, but I am using it in Android and the `notindexed` option isn't supported until SQLite 3.8, which Android doesn't support until [Android version 5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/3681880). And I need to support android 4.x. I am updating this question to include the Android tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FTS tables have an internal INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column called `docid` or `rowid`.
When inserting a row in the FTS table, set that column to the primary key of the row in the original table.

Then you can easily look up the corresponding row, either with a separate query, or with a join like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t2
WHERE id IN (SELECT docid
             FROM fts_table
             WHERE col_text MATCH 'something')
```

Comment: That would require a second query, right? And I would have to do that for every row that the FTS query returned, wouldn't I? Is there any way to do this with a single query (in order to return an Android cursor that contains multiple rows)?

Comment: but, with a query from other query It is not a more slow than only one fts query??

Comment: `id` is the primary key, so this lookup will be very fast. (This is pretty much the same mechanism that the DB would use for a search using a 'normal' index.)

Comment: @CL. What do you think about a contentless FTS table as an alternate to this method? (See the new answer below.) Does that already do the same thing that I was trying to accomplish in my question?