# Getting results from arbitrary SQL statements with correct binding in SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

The [SQLite.swift documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#executing-arbitrary-sql) says about executing arbitrary SQL:

```
let stmt = try db.prepare("SELECT id, email FROM users")
for row in stmt {
    for (index, name) in stmt.columnNames.enumerate() {
        print ("\(name)=\(row[index]!)")
        // id: Optional(1), email: Optional("alice@mac.com")
    }
}
```

I wanted to get the values directly like this

```
let stmt = try db.prepare("SELECT id, email FROM users")
for row in stmt {
    let myInt: Int64 = row[0] // error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding?' to specified type 'Int64'
    let myString: String = row[1] // error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding?' to specified type 'String'
}
```

but the row index is of type `Binding?` and I can't figure out how to convert that to the type I need. I see there is a `Statement.bind` method in the [source code](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/SQLite/Core/Statement.swift) but I am still not discovering how to apply it.

Comment: Did you try using `Expression`?, (eg. `let myInt: Expression<Int64> = ...`)

Comment: @l'L'l, Good idea. Unfortunately it gives the same error (can't convert `Binding?` to `Expression<Int64>`). I've been successful using `Expression` in the past but now that I am trying to get arbitrary SQL to work (because of my problem with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38936230)), I've been having a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can retrieve correctly typed selected columns from a table like this:

```swift
// The database.
let db = try Connection(...)

// The table.
let users = Table("users")

// Typed column expressions.
let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
let email = Expression<String>("email")

// The query: "SELECT id, email FROM users"
for user in try db.prepare(users.select(id, email)) {
    let id = user[id]       // Int64
    let mail = user[email]  // String
    print(id, mail)
}
```

An alternative is to (optionally) cast the `Binding` values
to the correct type:

```
let stmt = try db.prepare("SELECT id, email FROM users")
for row in stmt {
    if let id = row[0] as? Int64,
        let mail = row[1] as? String {
        print(id, mail)
    }
}
```

Comment: The second part of your answer solved my problem. The first part of your answer is surely better for the standard case (and I have done it like this before), but I am specifically wondering how to do it when executing arbitrary SQL. (I updated my question slightly to reflect that.) The reason I am resorting to arbitrary SQL is because of [this as of yet unsolved problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38936230).

Comment: Is there any way to bind the column names using `Expression` when accessing the row data after an arbitrary SQL query? I can see bugs coming in the future when I forget to update the hard coded column index numbers.

Comment: @Suragch: I doubt it. That would require to *analyze* the query string.